How can I use a DateRangePicker as a SingleDatePicker without force the option and lose the DateRange functionality?
I am using this DateRangePicker jQuery plugin and it works perfect for when you are using it with dates ranges but I want to be able also to select just one date without lose the range functionality. In other words: if you open both calendars and pick just a date from each then I want to be able to click the Apply button. My issue: the click event for the calendars is not exposed and therefore I am unable to catch when the user click and where.
I know the plugin offer a setting singleDatePicker that when it is set to true it shows only one calendar but this is not what I am looking for. If I force this then the second calendar isn't show up.
See my code below (Fiddle here):
$(document).ready(function () {
    const dateRangePicker = $('.dateRangePicker');
    dateRangePicker.daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        linkedCalendars: false,
        opens: 'left',
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        timePicker: false,
        format: 'm/d/Y'
    });

    dateRangePicker.on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        const startDate = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        const endDate = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');

        if (startDate === endDate) {
            $(this).val(startDate);
        } else {
            $(this).val(startDate + ' ... ' + endDate);
        }
    });

    dateRangePicker.on('showCalendar.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        $('.applyBtn').prop('disabled', true);
    });

    dateRangePicker.on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
    });
});

as soon as you click a date on any calendar then the plugin is forcing me to pick a second date which I would or wouldn't because in my form I can force always a range, I need to add the ability to choose a date or a range of dates.
Can I get some ideas for how to trick the plugin to achieve what I am looking for?
